# MacBook AirPlay doesn't see XBMC as a video output

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, macos

I have MacBook Pro (Early 2011, so I'm sure it supports AirPlay) and XBMC running on raspbmc. I have enabled AirPlay in XBMC.

Streaming audio works like a charm (I can select XBMC as an audio output). However, my Mac OS X doesn't see XBMC screen as a video ouput. Menu bar icon doesn't appear and System Settings window says `No Devices Detected`:

[image]

I would like to share videos and pictures I watch on my MacBook with XBMC. Ideally, I would like to mirror my screen too.

I've seen on the internet people successfully made it with iPad, so I'm sure it's possible. Mac OS X, however, seems to cause problems.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are both devices connected to the same router?

Comment: Can iTunes see XBMC?  If yes, the mirroring option may require encrypted airplay which XMBC does not provide.

Comment: @syb0org Yes, both devices use the same router.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen iTunes does see XBMC but when I try to select it it shows error message `An error occurred while connecting to the AirPlay device “XBMC (raspbmc)”. An unknown error occurred (-15000).`. What's inttersting, when I select XBMC as an audio output (by clicking speaker icon in the menu bar while pressing the Option key) iTunes does see it and streams music to XBMC properly.

Comment: I would suggest opening a bug report with XBMC.  This might be either a configuration issue, your router not being 100% compatible or a bug in the XBMC airplay implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Airplay mirroring on Raspberry Pi with rPlay](https://adventuresandwhathaveyou.wordpress.com/2013/09/02/airplay-mirroring-on-raspberry-pi-with-rplay/).

Please note that you will need a key to operate it in Mirror mode.

Comment: Got AirPlay mirroring successfully working, finally. Although it complains about ALSA and freezes sometimes, it starts and works, for some time at least. I'll continue solving the issues on rPlay forums. Thanks for suggesting rPlay!